# Numbering each line in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

In my following script

```
atind=[5,37,43,55,75,85,104,127,141,147,168,182,197,203,213,235,245,269,288,307,331,352,372,393,407,417,439,449,456,475,485,502,516,536,552,573,580,587,597,621,631,653,677,691,705,725,747,758,768,783,795,805,822,846,860,870,877,884]
for f in feat.describe_features(ds[0]):
    [a,b]=f['resseqs']
    print("d: DISTANCE ATOMS=%d,%d"%(atind[a-1], atind[b-1]))
```

I got an output like

```
d: DISTANCE ATOMS=85,141
d: DISTANCE ATOMS=85,147
d: DISTANCE ATOMS=85,168
d: DISTANCE ATOMS=85,182
d: DISTANCE ATOMS=85,197
d: DISTANCE ATOMS=85,203
d: DISTANCE ATOMS=85,213
```

.....there are more than 1000 lines like this what I want is an way so that I can edit my script to number the outputs like

```
d1: DISTANCE ATOMS=85,141
d2: DISTANCE ATOMS=85,147
d3: DISTANCE ATOMS=85,168
d4: DISTANCE ATOMS=85,182
d5: DISTANCE ATOMS=85,197
d6: DISTANCE ATOMS=85,203
d7: DISTANCE ATOMS=85,213
```

...till the last one.

Any cool trick to do that. I can do it in bash but it is too much of a work. I think I am missing very basic Python way of doing it. Any help will be highly appreciated.

I guess it should be a variable after `d$i` something like that maybe not?

Comment: You are already using `%d` correctly. Why not once more?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `enumerate` for your iterator to yield index-value pairs:

```
for i, f in enumerate(feat.describe_features(ds[0]), start=1):
    [a,b]=f['resseqs']
    print("d%d: DISTANCE ATOMS=%d,%d"%(i, atind[a-1], atind[b-1]))
```

If using Python 3.6+, also note that you can use an *f-string* for better formatting:

```
for i, f in enumerate(feat.describe_features(ds[0]), start=1):
    a, b = f['resseqs']
    print(f"d{i}: DISTANCE ATOMS={atind[a - 1]},{atind[b - 1]}")
```

Comment: Yes great. Thanks a million

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this :

```
list = [ "abc", "def" , "mno"]
for i,c in enumerate(list):
    print i,c
```